# is it worthwhile to choose a less attractive domain name to get the .com extension?

Tags: blog, ecommerce, top-level-domains, domain-extension

I have to purchase a second level domain and choosing the name for my website, which is basically a comic strips blog. That's to say it doesn't have commercial purposes mainly, but I don't exclude the possibility of selling merchandasing through it.
I found several names so far, they are all related with the website content, and I want to choose one of them; the more suitable (shorter, more cute and cooler) aren't available with the *.com* extension.
If I need the *.com* extension I should opte for a more compound name, that's to say I would sacrifice its attractivity for a better top level domain. But is it really better?

I wonder:

- What is the best between a coleer name with the *.net* extension and a less attractive one which lets me getting the *.com* top level domain?

Comment: We can really only offer opinions here, which is considered off-topic. Traditionally however, [.net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.net) was associated with either networking technologies or the network-side of an organization. If the `.com` version isn't available, you might consider one of the [new gTLDs](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings) instead (e.g., `.blog`), which are treated equally in terms of search engine rankings and might be more memorable to your users than a `.net` one.

Comment: thank you @dan . Do you think that in this specific case  the .blog extension may be better than the .net one?

Comment: Unless there's a gTLD extension that you think is better suited in the list I linked to in my comment (e.g., `.book`), I would think `.blog` would be a lot more descriptive and better fit than `.net`, since you're hosting a comic strip _blog_ and not a _network_ related site. That should give you a lot more flexibility in selecting a cool name too :-)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm also worried about the impact such extension might have on average users, for a .net extension may be perceived as more reliable and comfortable maybe... Am I wrong?

Comment: People are getting much more used to the new extensions, and personally I think `.net` domains used for general purposes has always seemed a bit odd. A valid question to ask yourself is: "Would I naturally think to type in `.net` for a comic strip blog...and do I know of any popular ones that use `.net`?" There are lots of well-funded startups using the new gTLDs, and seems like a lot more progressive/hip than using a `.net` domain (no offense to any _.net'ers_ who might read this).